# Impossible to Delete Catalina Installers

Tags: trash

I've tried to delete the Catalina installer twice - and both instances have become stuck in Trash.

Trying to empty Trash via GUI results in 'operation can't be completed because item is in use` errors. Same thing when I reboot into safe mode and try to empty Trash again.

```
sudo rm -rf ~filename
```

gives 'operation not permitted' and then 'directory not empty` errors

```
ls -laO
```

show no flags set for the files. So no impediment there.

I've also tried the third-party deletion tool Trash It! on it's most aggressive setting to no success.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/Owza1Gl]

This is what the two files look like in Trash. I've never seen those icons before. I'd say it was something installer related but the Big Sur installer deleted without issue. I'm not sure what steps to take next.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot delete it normally, you can either attempt to find what *file* is keeping it from being deleted or just delete it from **macOS Recovery**.

To check for an open file that's in the **Trash**, from **Terminal**:

```
lsof | grep '.Trash'
```

Or **macOS Recovery**:

From **macOS**, running normally, open **Terminal** and execute the following *compound command* to reboot to **macOS Recovery**:

```
sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"; sleep 2; sudo reboot
```

In **macOS Recovery**, open **Terminal** from the **Utilities** menu and run the following *commands*:

```
find /Volumes -maxdepth 4 -type d -name '.Trash'
```

On my system it returned:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me/.Trash
/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Users/me/.Trash
```

Then *change directory* to your **.Trash** *directory*, either one if two are listed for the target user, delete the **.app** *application bundle*, and reboot:

```
cd '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me/.Trash'
rm -r *.app
reboot
```

---

Or from **Terminal** in **macOS Recovery** you can simply run the following *compound command* and it will delete all **.Trash** *directories* and reboot. The **.Trash** *directories* will be recreated automatically when logging into your account.

```
find /Volumes -maxdepth 4 -type d -name '.Trash' -exec rm -r '{}' \; 2>/dev/null; reboot
```

Comment: Worked exactly as described. So much time wasted on bad Google answers. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to avoid having to use the macOS Recovery mode, an easy solution is to **move the installer to `/tmp`** directory:

```
sudo mv Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app /tmp
```

Next, **reboot your machine** as this makes macOS empty anything under `/tmp`.